# At what minimum distance does the Earth appear star-like to the naked eye?

Tags: earth-observation, tesla-roadster, altitude

At what distance does the Earth become indistinguishable from stars and other planets to the naked eye, like the [Pale Blue Dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pale_Blue_Dot) or like Venus or Mars visible from Earth? Dot-like rather than spherical.

As the Tesla Roadster with Starman was launched towards Mars and the main asteroid belt, at what distance would one no longer recognize the Earth and Moon as spherical bodies from the Tesla Roadster?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Dot-like rather than spherical, as written in the question body. When you look on Venus or Mars with the naked eye you don't see whether it's a star or a planet (Mars appears reddish but that's Betelgeuse too), you don't see them as globes but star-like.

Comment: When I looked at Venus during the last transit before the Sun, I could see it clearly as a small circle. Venus is seen as 9.7 to 66 arcseconds. So my eyes with glasses seem to be better than one arcminute.

Comment: @Uwe Venus should appear as a crescent aside transits.

Comment: At bright sunlight the angle resolution of the human eyes is better than at night. So I saw the Venus at transit and minimal distance as a small disk, but in the night at greater distance only as a bright star but not as a crescent.

Comment: Clearly this is going to depend on the individual. I've encountered people (like @Uwe) who claim that they can spot the planets by eye for Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn and I've never been able to see any of them as anything but little dots just like stars.

Comment: @SteveCox Mars tends to be a distinctive color, so that makes it easy to identify. Venus tends to appear in certain places near dawn or sunset ("morning star" or "evening star") and is characteristically bright, so it's also easy to find. Jupiter and Saturn, IME, are rather more difficult to distinguish unless you know where you are looking and what to expect there.

Comment: The bright planets have such an angular extent that they shine with a steady intensity and do not twinkle, as do stars. The twinkle effect is caused by perturbations in the atmosphere as the light rays refract through layers of air of different density (hence refractive index). For a very thin ray (from a star) this is a significant effect. For the broader beam from a planet, the effect is much less. An easy way to identify planets. That, and they're always on the ecliptic.

Comment: @OscarBravo Aren't there (fixed) stars that don't twinkle?

Comment: @LoveForChrist I don't so.. The largest is about 0.06 arc-secs angular diameter. Planets are roughly in the 10-50 arc-secs range, so ~50 times larger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The visual acuity of a healthy human eye is about 1 arcminute (a full circle is 360°, 1 ° is divided into 60 arcminutes).

A football with a diameter of 220 mm at a distance of about 775 m subtends an angle of 1 arcminute. Or a tiny object of 0.2908 mm at a distance of 1 m.

The Earth diameter is 12742 km. So the distance is 43,8 million km or 0.293 AU as @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic notes.

The diameter of the Moon is 3474.8 km, the distance to see it as an arcminute only is 11.9 million km.

Comment: So within 43 million km (~27 million mi) you recognize the Earth as a blue planet, with continents and clouds or something?

Comment: Venus can be a sliver of almost 60 arc seconds tall, and Jupiter can get to almost 50, and yet I'm not sure if either of those is ever noticeably extended, so I think this is an upper limit. [Can you see the difference with the naked eye whether Venus is at the other side of the Sun or at the Earths' side?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36232/7982) and also [Venus' magnitude during inferior conjunction](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33797/7982)

Comment: The distance to resolve the continents and clouds of Earth is much smaller than 43 million km. At 4.3 million km the human eye would resolve it as 10 pixels wide and high,

Comment: @LoveForChris No, you can't see clouds and continents that are much smaller than the earth at that distance. Your question asked what the minimum distance is to see the extreme points of the earth resolved. Obviously the minimum distance for smaller objects will be different.

Comment: Info about distinguishing features on Earth at lunar distance here: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41967/6944

Comment: @uhoh I remember the Venus transit, I have seen Venus noticeably extended as a small black disk before the Sun. But it was at bright sunlight and minimal distance of Venus.

Comment: This answer is much more intuitive to me expressed as 0.287 au.

Comment: @Uwe oh I see, in that geometry it was a full circle rather than a sliver, *very nice!*

Comment: This [article](https://www.space.com/39701-earth-moon-40-million-miles-nasa-photo.html) shows a photo of the Earth at a distance of 63 million km.  It fits nicely with this answer.